# an upper set is of the form $[a, \infty) $ if it has the least element $a$

Tags: real-analysis

$(DEF):$ Let $X$ be a totally ordered set. A set $A \subset X$ is called an upper set if $a \in A $ and $x > a $ implies $x \in A $.

Suppose $A \subset X$ is an upper set that has the least element $a$, then $A = [a, \infty) $

I can prove one direction: If $y \in [a, \infty)$, then $y \geq a $ and we know $a \in A$, then by definition $x \in A $. So, $[a, \infty) \subset A $.

I am stuck trying to prove that $A \subset [a, \infty) $. May I ask for some help? thanks

Comment: $y \in A \Rightarrow y\geq a$ (by assumption of 'a' being least element in A) thus $y \in [a,\infty)$. Thus $A \subset [a,\infty)$.

Comment: As a guideline for future efforts: note that you had used the fact $a\in A$ in your half proof, but you hadn't yet used the fact that $a$ was the *least* element of $A$ (and indeed the statement would be false without that point). So that could be a hint to try to use this fact in the second half of the proof.